# Why is my default button on Android Studio is not like default?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, button, uibutton

[So i don't know what happen but my default button look like this, and i'm pretty sure default button on android studio is not like that. Anyone know how to get my button back to default? because right now my button look like that and i can't even customize my button. Thank you for your answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUGZe.png)

I tried to change the theme on the button and the activity but it change nothing

Comment: Hi, could you provide xml codes ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no any default button style in android studio and the button reads its property from the theme. (it's not only for buttons but also for all views).

The button's style which is shown in your picture has Material 3 style, I guess you are looking for the Material 2 theme so you can create another project without M3 theme or migrate your current project's theme to M2.

by the way, to see the changes in your layout preview make sure that the theme which is selected in the drop-down menu at above of preview screen is selected correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Material 3. and in Material 3 This is the default style for the button.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by default button ? You need to change your theme bro that's it